# multiplying both sides of a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am working through the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" By Gilbert Strang and I have come across an equation on page 176 which I cannot get my head around.

This is dealing with orthonormal matrices $Q$ and the equation $Qx = b$

> write b as a combination $b = x_1q_1 + x_2q_2 + ... + x_nq_n$
>
> To compute $x_1$ there is a neat trick *Multiply both sides of the equation* by $q_1^T$. On the left-hand side is $q_1^Tb$. On the right-hand side all terms disappear (because $q_1^Tq_j = 0$ except for the first term. We are left with

$$
q_1^Tb = x_1q_1^Tq_1
$$

and since $q_1^Tq_1 = 1$

$$
x_1 = q_1^Tb
$$

My question is about the order of the terms on the right side of the equation. Since order matters, wouldn't it have to be written $q_1^Tx_1q_1$ since the multiplication on the left side was inserted from the left?

Comment: In the last equation it should be $q_1^Tb=x_1$.  As written you have a transposed vector equal to a scalar.  I find the notation confusing because $x$ is a vector but $x_1$ etc. are the eigenvalues and scalars.  It would be better to use $\lambda_i$ for the eigenvalues, but presumably that comes from the text.

Comment: fixed the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x_1$ is just a scalar,  so $q_1^Tx_1q_1=x_1q_1^Tq_1$.

Comment: so then $x_1$ is a scalar, but $q_1$ is the first column vector of $Q$?

Comment: Yes.  Apparently.

Comment: That makes sense now, but it was confusing in the text. Thanks

Comment: You bet.  I used to have a copy of it. But it was lost in the shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)^t$ and that $q_j$ is the $j$-th column of $Q$. So, in the equation
$$Qx=x_1q_1+x_2q_2+\cdots+x_nq_n$$
we have a linear combination of the vectors $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n$ with coefficients $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.
Therefore, for all $j$ we have
$$q_1^t (x_jq_j)=x_j(q_1^tq_j)$$
($x_j$ is just a scalar, more precisely, the $j$-th component of $x$)